# Making my own Vector. Whats wrong with it?

Tags: c++, vector

i am trying to make my own vector but i cant get it to work as i want.
I get a error message on the Move-constructor it says: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF751A77ACC in auto-tests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The first one got solved. But now i got the same error with another part of the code. The push_back finction, here is the code.

Here is the code for the move-constructor:

```
template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(Vector&& other)
    : m_nrOfElements(other.m_nrOfElements), m_capacity(other.m_capacity)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nrOfElements; i++)
    {
        m_elements[i] = other.m_elements[i];   /// HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS!
    }

    other.m_elements = nullptr;
    other.m_capacity = 0;
    other.m_nrOfElements = 0;
}
```

Comment: In your own words, why should `m_elements[i] = other.m_elements[i]` be possible? What is the size of `m_elements`; where and how is the space allocated; and what part of the code is supposed to make that happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. "I am grateful for any answer" is not a question. A question (one that's properly specific for the site) looks something like "why does ABC happen?" or "how do I make XYZ happen instead?".

Comment: That's a *move* constructor anyway, thus you should *move* the data instead of copying it! As `m_elements` is a pointer, you'd have `Vector(Vector&& other) : m_elements(other.m_elements)` instead – or default construct the empty vector and just `swap` the contents (you might want to support swapping anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for `m_elements` - and you shouldn't, since this is a *move constructor*. Just use [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) to "steal" the pointer from `other` and replace it with the value you desire - that is, `nullptr`.

Example:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
inline Vector<T>::Vector(Vector&& other)
    : m_nrOfElements(std::exchange(other.m_nrOfElements, 0),
      m_capacity(std::exchange(other.m_capacity, 0),
      m_elements(std::exchange(other.m_elements, nullptr))
{
    // constructor body can now be empty
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it fixed the issue. But now i am getting another error. Heap corruption detected. i guess i need to throw in a malloc somewhere in the code.

Comment: @TylerDurden Assignment is similar, in the move you `std::swap` each member. Copy needs to allocate, Move steals the existing allocation.

Comment: Ok, i will do that. I edited this question, and it need debugging details.. So i dont think i can accept your answer somewhere, or? Im really new here.